# ionic 3 - UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning when generating android build

Tags: android, build, apk, ionic3

I am using ionic 3.19 and when I try to create an android build it has the following error. With ios its fine. What is this problem and how to solve this ?

I am using node v8.9.1.

```
(node:49779) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: spawn EACCES
```

Here is the execution and the problem output

```
$ ionic cordova build android --release
Running app-scripts build: --platform android --target cordova
[18:01:13]  build dev started ... 
[18:01:13]  clean started ... 
[18:01:13]  clean finished in 6 ms 
[18:01:13]  copy started ... 
[18:01:13]  deeplinks started ... 
[18:01:13]  deeplinks finished in 97 ms 
[18:01:13]  transpile started ... 
[18:01:17]  transpile finished in 4.06 s 
[18:01:17]  preprocess started ... 
[18:01:17]  preprocess finished in less than 1 ms 
[18:01:17]  webpack started ... 
[18:01:17]  copy finished in 4.30 s 
[18:01:25]  webpack finished in 7.47 s 
[18:01:25]  sass started ... 
Without `from` option PostCSS could generate wrong source map and will not find Browserslist config. Set it to CSS file path or to `undefined` to prevent this warning.
[18:01:26]  sass finished in 1.26 s 
[18:01:26]  postprocess started ... 
[18:01:26]  postprocess finished in 13 ms 
[18:01:26]  lint started ... 
[18:01:26]  build dev finished in 13.04 s 
> cordova build android --release
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/megasap/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home
(node:49779) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: spawn EACCES
(node:49779) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

[18:01:29]  tslint: src/pages/attandance-detail/attandance-detail.ts, line: 175 
            'marker' is declared but never used. 

     L174:  console.log(location)
     L175:  let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     L176:      position: location,

[18:01:29]  tslint: src/pages/home/home.ts, line: 260 
            'marker' is declared but never used. 

     L259:  addMarker(location, map) {
     L260:      let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     L261:          position: location,

[18:01:29]  lint finished in 3.00 s
```

UPDATE:
This is the execution and error with node v9.4.0. This has a bit more detail than the previous running on node v8.9.1. 
https://gist.github.com/axilaris/4cc7094c7dae28477eb2f348e53fad91

Comment: Have you resolved it?

Comment: yes! wait a sec

Answer (score 3):

this did the trick!

sudo chmod 777 /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-4.1/bin/gradle

Comment: Thanx! It's a horrible error message for this simlpe problem :/

Comment: `chmod +x .../bin/gradle` would be cleaner

Comment: If anyone use windows then what?

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem and after updating Android Studio and it updated gradle from 4.1 to 4.4 then I had to update my environment variable and go to the new gradle location `/opt/android-studio/gradle/gradle-4.4/bin` and do `chmod 777 gradle`